# if statement failing in lua

Tags: if-statement, lua

I have the following test lua code:

```
   err = nextUsernumber
   res = false 
   if not res and err then
      print("error")
      errtxt = err
   end
```

But the logic never enters into the if statement.

I've tried putting brackets() around the if clauses, like so:

```
if (not res) and (err) then
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `if ... then` (see the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.4)):

```
if not res and err then
  print("error")
  errtxt = err
end
```

Also, make sure that `err` is neither `nil` nor `false` as both are regarded as false in control statements (see the section of the manual as above).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `then` clause. Lua needs a `then` statement for if.

```
if not res and err then
    print("error")
    errtxt = err
end
```

Comment: hi there.  I apparently didn't cut and paste properly.  I do have a "then" in my code.